# Boot issue while using u-boot with Raspberry Pi 4 in 32-bit

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues, bootloader, u-boot

I am trying to integrate 32bit u-boot for Raspberry Pi 4B 32bit. Below are my steps:

1. Installed Raspbian (bookworm) 32bit on SD card using Raspberry Pi Imager.
2. Built u-boot binary using `rpi_4_32b_defconfig` and `CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-`.
3. Copied the `u-boot.bin` to SD card as `kernel7l.img`
4. Converted actual kernel `kernel7l.img` to uImage using

```
mkimage -A arm -O linux -T kernel -C none -a 0x00008000 -e 0x00008000 -n "Linux kernel" -d kernel7l.img uImage
```

And copied `uImage` to SD card

5. Modified `config.txt` to include `enable_uart=1` , `arm_64bit=0` (if this is not added then 64bit `kernel8.img` is loaded by default and `u-boot` is ignored
6. Created `boot.scr` using command

```
mkimage -A arm -O linux -T script -C none -n "Boot script" -d boot.txt boot.scr
```

The `boot.txt` contains

```
fdt addr  && fdt get value bootargs /chosen bootargs
fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} uImage
bootm ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr}
```

However when I try to boot, I get below errors:

```
.
.
MESS:00:00:05.191876:0: hdmi: HDMI1:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 0
MESS:00:00:05.196898:0: hdmi: HDMI1:EDID giving up on reading EDID block 0
MESS:00:00:05.202495:0: hdmi: HDMI:hdmi_get_state is deprecated, use hdmi_get_display_state instead
MESS:00:00:05.211260:0: HDMI0: hdmi_pixel_encoding: 300000000
MESS:00:00:05.216728:0: HDMI1: hdmi_pixel_encoding: 300000000
MESS:00:00:06.596395:0: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/initramfs7l
MESS:00:00:06.598939:0: Loaded 'initramfs7l' to 0x0 size 0xf6978c
MESS:00:00:06.617302:0: initramfs loaded to 0x2e096000 (size 0xf6978c)
MESS:00:00:06.625010:0: dtb_file 'bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb'
MESS:00:00:06.627041:0: brfs: File read: 16160652 bytes
MESS:00:00:06.637923:0: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
MESS:00:00:06.641165:0: Loaded 'bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb' to 0x100 size 0xd5b3
MESS:00:00:06.661027:0: brfs: File read: 54707 bytes
MESS:00:00:06.673941:0: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/overlays/overlay_map.dtb
MESS:00:00:06.703128:0: brfs: File read: 4871 bytes
MESS:00:00:06.707559:0: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/config.txt
MESS:00:00:06.710292:0: dtparam: audio=on
MESS:00:00:06.718973:0: brfs: File read: 1220 bytes
MESS:00:00:06.735588:0: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/overlays/vc4-kms-v3d-pi4.dtbo
MESS:00:00:06.801900:0: Loaded overlay 'vc4-kms-v3d'
MESS:00:00:06.967321:0: brfs: File read: 3913 bytes
MESS:00:00:06.971115:0: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/cmdline.txt
MESS:00:00:06.974501:0: Read command line from file 'cmdline.txt':
MESS:00:00:06.980369:0: 'console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=c5f0af41-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles'
MESS:00:00:07.116245:0: brfs: File read: 147 bytes
MESS:00:00:07.177872:0: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/kernel7l.img
MESS:00:00:07.180513:0: Loaded 'kernel7l.img' to 0x8000 size 0x9d680
MESS:00:00:07.186606:0: Device tree loaded to 0x2e088500 (size 0xda23)
MESS:00:00:07.194921:0: uart: Set PL011 baud rate to 103448.300000 Hz
MESS:00:00:07.201908:0: uart: Baud rate change done...
MESS:00:00:07.203930:0:

U-Boot 2023.10-dirty (Feb 20 2024 - 08:33:14 +0100)

DRAM:  948 MiB (effective 3.9 GiB)
RPI 4 Model B (0xc03115)
Core:  211 devices, 16 uclasses, devicetree: board
MMC:   mmcnr@7e300000: 1, mmc@7e340000: 0
Loading Environment from FAT... Unable to read "uboot.env" from mmc0:1...
In:    serial,usbkbd
Out:   serial,vidconsole
Err:   serial,vidconsole
Net:   eth0: ethernet@7d580000
PCIe BRCM: link up, 5.0 Gbps x1 (SSC)
PCI: Failed autoconfig bar 10
starting USB...
Bus xhci_pci: pci_hose_bus_to_phys: invalid physical address
xhci-pci init cannot map PCI mem bar
probe failed, error -5
No working controllers found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
Card did not respond to voltage select! : -110
Bus xhci_pci: pci_hose_bus_to_phys: invalid physical address
xhci-pci init cannot map PCI mem bar
probe failed, error -5
No working controllers found
ethernet@7d580000 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
bcmgenet: PHY startup failed: -110
ethernet@7d580000 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
bcmgenet: PHY startup failed: -110
U-Boot>
```

When I try to manually boot using boot.txt commands: I get

```
fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} uImage
7465016 bytes read in 349 ms (20.4 MiB/s)
bootm ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr}
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
```

What is the issue here and how can I resolve it?

Comment: RPi doesn't **typically** use `u-boot`... What makes you think this will work at all? (Just curious).